# Keyboard prints in reverse

Tags: keyboard, dell-studio-xps-16

My Dell Studio laptop is printing in reverse. For example if I type "and" it gives "dna".How can I check if it is a hardware or a software issue from ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: It sounds like you may have right-to-left language support enabled, possibly? Does this happen in all programs on your computer, including the terminal, Firefox, and LibreOffice, or just a specific one? Check your keyboard/input/language preferences to see if "right to left alanguage support" (or similar) has been accidentally enabled.

Comment: This happens in every program. And also sometimes, when I scroll down it automatically scrolls back to the top of the page and stays there.

Comment: I'm not on my Ubuntu computer right now, so I forget what it's called, but I'd recommend taking a look through Ubuntu's preferences menus. Look for "language support", "keyboard", "input method", or similar. Then look for a "right-to-left language support" option (or similar) to see if you can disable it.